# How to pass data from one view into another view using sessions variable in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

`HTML`

```
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'doctor:search' %}">
        <input name ="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="search..">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
            Search
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to save {{request.GET.q}} from this html into session variable and use it in all the views

`ORIGINAL VIEWS.PY`

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Search
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
        return object_list


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/post_form.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'comment']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.patient = User.objects.get(username=query)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

[query = self.request.GET.get('q')] in 'SearchResultsView' and in 'PostCreateView' needs same value. I want to use input value from html and use it in both these classes using session variable

`VIEWS.PY` Trying to implement session variable

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Search
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        **request.session['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')**
        **query = request.session['query']**
        object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
        return object_list


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/post_form.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'comment']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        **query = request.session['query']**
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.patient = User.objects.get(username=query)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

When i use this code i get "name 'request' is not defined" error.

Comment: are you calling 2 views from a single `doctor:search` url ?

Comment: no doctor:search url calls SearchResultView. Later on PostCreateView is called using doctor:post-create url.

Comment: and in which template are you calling `doctor:post-create url` ?

Comment: It's another template which is same as template above  only difference is {% url 'doctor:post-create' %}

Comment: just a guess but i think you missing self in the request of form_valid try `query = self.request.session['query']`. Would be helpful to post full traceback error in your question so we know which template having the error

Comment: I tried it but the error shows up in `request.session['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')` this line  as `name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: you need to set request for that view too so it's `self.request.session['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')` or add request to the get_query `get_queryset(self, request)` either of those should be correct

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me.

Comment: glad to help, i will post my answer instead of just comment, which one of the suggestion i gave work ?

Comment: sure thank you once again. `self.request.session['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')` this one worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from my answer in the comment of the question. The reason you didn't your request doesn't get defined because it's not within the scope of the view when it run.So you need to call `self` on the view:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Search
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
      self.request.session['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q') #using the request on the running
      query = self.request.session['query']
      object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
      return object_list


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/post_form.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'comment']

    def form_valid(self, form):
      query = self.request.session['query']
      form.instance.author = self.request.user
      form.instance.patient = User.objects.get(username=query)
      return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: HI I am in a similar dilemma. Could you check my query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140183/how-to-use-django-sessions-framework-in-generic-views-to-send-data-to-another)? Thanks.